# Problem where I am getting a negative variance

Tags: probability, statistics

In Finan's Probability Book 17.20:

*Let $X$ be a random variable. Define $Z= {X−E(X)\over σ_X}$.  Find $E(Z)$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Z)$.*

If I am understanding correctly, ${X−E(X)\over σ_X}={X−E(X)\over\sqrt{E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2}}$

So the variance should be $E\left({X−E(X)\over\sqrt{E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2}}\right)^2-\left[E\left({X−E(X)\over\sqrt{E(X^2)-{[E(X)]}^2}}\right)\right]^2$

which should equal to

$$\left({E(X)^2−2E(X)^2+[E(X)]^2\over{E(X^2)-{[E(X)]}^2}}\right)-\left({[E(X)−E(X)]^2\over{E(X^2)-{[E(X)]}^2}}\right) =  -1-0$$

but the answer for the variance is $1$, and I have heard that a negative variance is impossible anyways, so which step did I get wrong?

Comment: You expanded the numerator of the first piece incorrectly, make sure you clearly differentiate between $E(X^2)$ and $[E(X)]^2$, so you dont confuse yourself

Comment: Sorry, I can't see which part you are referring to, is it $\left({E(X)^2−2E(X)^2+[E(X)]^2\over{E(X^2)-{[E(X)]}^2}}\right)$?

Comment: Yes, the numerator is incorrect, first expand $(X-E(X))^2$, and then apply the expected value operator noting that $E(X)$ is a constant and can be pulled through the operator, and you should get the correct answer

Comment: I expanded that to ${(X)^2−2E(X)^2+[E(X)]^2}$ and then I did $E\left[{(X)^2−2E(X)^2+[E(X)]^2)}\right]$ = $E(X)^2−2E(X)^2+[E(X)]^2$. Which step was incorrect?

Comment: When you take $E(X^2)$, you are taking the expectation of the random variable $X^2$, i.e $E(X^2)$, which is not the same as $E(X)^2$, as you wrote. So the first time you applied the expectation operator was incorrect. Also your original expansion was incorrect. $(X- E(X))^2 = X^2 - 2E(X)(X) + E(X)^2$. It just so happened that the way the expectations played out, you got the second term correct, but convince yourself why this is the case

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I guess I am just confused about the difference between $E(X)^2$ and $E(X^2)$. Is $E(X)^2$ the same as $[E(X)]^2$ ?

Comment: Yes, remember that the expected value of a random variable is just a number, synonymous with a mean. So when you are saying $E(X)^2$ or $[E(X)]^2$, you are basically just saying that you are squaring some number. When you refer to $E(X^2)$, this means you are finding the mean of a different random variable. To give you a concrete example, say your random variable X is that of a dice i.e. one sixth probability for integers 1 through 6. Then E(X) = 3.5(mean of a dice roll), but E(X^2) which associated one sixth probability to squares 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36 has mean 91/6 which is not equal to 3.5^2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake when you expanded the brackets.

To make it simpler: $$\operatorname{Var}(\frac{X-E(X)}{\sigma(X)})= \frac{\operatorname{Var}(X-E(X))}{\operatorname{Var}(X)} = \frac{E(X^2-2XE(X)+E(X)^2)-E(X-E(X))^2}{E(X^2)-E(X)^2}. $$

Here, $E(X-E(X))=0,$ so $E(X-E(X))^2=0.$

Furthermore, $E(X^2-2XE(X)+E(X)^2)= E(X^2)-2E(X)^2+E(X)^2= E(X^2)-E(X)^2.$

So the desired variance is $$\frac{E(X^2)-E(X)^2}{E(X^2)-E(X)^2}=1.$$

Comment: The formatting is fine, but with mathjax (used on this site, you need to include dollar signs around the formatted portions.

Comment: click on the link to edit the post, to view the changes I made.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am just getting used to this site!

Comment: No problem!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

$Z = \frac {X-E[X]}{\sigma_X}= \frac {X}{\sigma_X}-\frac {E[X]}{\sigma_X}\\
E[Z]= E[\frac {X}{\sigma_X}-\frac{E[X]}{\sigma_X}] = \frac {E[X]}{\sigma_X} - \frac {E[X]}{\sigma_X} = 0$

Which means that 
$var(Z) = E[Z^2]-E[Z]^2 = E[Z^2] = E[(\frac {X}{\sigma_X} - \frac {E[X]}{\sigma_X})^2]= \frac {1}{\sigma^2_X}E[(X - E[X])^2] = \frac {\sigma^2_X}{\sigma^2_X} = 1$

As for your work...
$E\left({X−E(X)\over\sqrt{E(X^2)-{[E(X)]}^2}}\right)^2=E\left({X^2−2XE(X)+E(X)^2\over E(X^2)+{[E(X)]}^2}\right)\ne\left({E(X)^2−2E(X)^2+[E(X)]^2\over{E(X^2)-{[E(X)]}^2}}\right)$

Comment: "I think that this is where your mistake lies" No, that wasn't the mistake. OP wrote $E(X)^2$ instead of $E(X^2)$ when computing $E(Z^2)$.